# Select two lists as one list in ASP.NET Core linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a query with ASP.NET Core EF Core and Linq that would give me a List of users based on two different lists, something like this:

```
return await _context.Users
            .Include(u => u.PropertyOwners)
                .ThenInclude(po => po.Property)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.PropertyTenantLeases)
            .Include(u => u.PropertyOwners)
                .ThenInclude(po => po.Owner)
            .Where(u => u.Id == userID)
            .Select(u => new List<User>() 
            { 
                u.PropertyTenantLeases.Select(ptl => ptl.Tenant).ToList()
                u.PropertyOwners.Select(po => po.Owner).ToList() 
            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The tables that are used in this query are connected in the following way:
[image: Table design]
Everything is fine with this query except for the Select, with the Select I am trying to achieve that it returns a list of all the tenants in the PropertyTenantLeases table which is a junction table togheter with all the Owners form the PropertyOwners junction table (both Tenant and Owner are IdentityUser classes. When I right this query like this I get the following error:

```
The best overloeaded Add method 'List<User>.Add(User)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
```

and also

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RosyMasterDBManagement.Models.User>' to 'RosyMasterDBManagement.Models.User'
```

Comment: how exactly is this two times -- looks like one time to me.

Comment: Yeah this is not working, I am asking how to do something like this.

Comment: Not understand...Could you show your models and your expected result?

Comment: Asking how to do something like what?  We can't read your mind we need to understand to help.  The best way to do this is to show the starting data and the expected results.  Also if this code is giving an error you should show that too.

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully you have all the info you now.

Comment: I think I know what you want but I can't be sure.  You will have to show us information about your data model -- what does a user object look like -- what PropertyTenantLeases and PropertyOwners contain.  Without this information I would just be guessing.

Comment: Added the database design for the used tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining two list is called a union in Linq -- I believe that is what you want:

> note: I still can't test this since you gave a picture of the data model instead of the code that would allow me to be certain of how to implement.  expect the fields to be named incorrectly etc.

```
var ownerlist = _context.Users
            .Include(u => u.PropertyOwners)
                .ThenInclude(po => po.Owner)
            .ToList();

var tenantlist = _context.Users
            .Include(u => u.PropertyOwners)
                .ThenInclude(po => po.Property)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.PropertyTenantLeases)
                      .ThenInclude(po => po.Tenant)
            .ToList();

return ownerlist.Union(tenantlist);
```

I don't believe you need await() since ToList() forces it to not be lazy.  But I could be wrong about that.